# chrome:// like URLs in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, bho

once again, I'm struggling with porting a Firefox extension to Internet Explorer 7, 8 and 9.

My most recent problem is that the FF extension code makes heavy use of AJAX calls to "chrome://..." urls (it fetches .html files that way and then displays the HTML on the page).

Is there any way in IE to access "chrome://"-like URLs? Or - more generally - is there any way I can make an AJAX call to retrieve contents of a HTML file that is a part of the extension (and is not accessible online)?

Thanks a lot!

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the res:// scheme.  This [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is .net specific, but it gives you the basics of how the protocol is used.

Comment: Thanks! Now I just have to find out how to embed the html files into the DLL (but I will just google that out). :-)

Comment: Just store the HTML in a resource file.  Use RT_HTML and you should be set.